# Convert a decimal matrix to a binary matrix in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

Suppose I have a integer matrix which represents who has emailed whom and how many times. For social network analysis I'd like to make a simple undirected graph. So I need to convert the matrix to binary matrix and later into a list of tuples.

My question: is there a fast, convenient way to reduce the decimal matrix to a binary matrix.

Such that:

```
26, 3, 0
3, 195, 1
0, 1, 17
```

Becomes:

```
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
0, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `scipy.sign` function to every cell in the matrix.

[EDIT] Cudos to [speciousfool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39584/speciousfool):

If `x` is your matrix then `scipy.sign(x)` gives you the binary matrix.

Comment: If x is your matrix then:

scipy.sign(x)

gives you the binary matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> a = scipy.array((12, 0, -1, 23, 0))
array([12,  0, -1, 23,  0])
>>> (a != 0).astype(int)
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

The magic is in the `a != 0` part. You can apply boolean expressions to arrays and it will return an array of booleans. Then it is converted to ints.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
>>>x,y = scipy.where(yourMatrix>0)
>>>yourMatrix[:,:] = 0
>>>yourMatrix[x,y] = 1
```

i guess this will also be faster.